# I think this integration with the jacobian problem isn't possible.

Tags: calculus, integration, jacobian

When I substitute $x^2-x y+y^2$ with $u$ and $v$, I get $2u+2v$. This implies that the bounds of integration become $2u+2v=2$, which is a line. We haven't been taught that the jacobian is allowed to transform $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^1$, so I think the problem is not as intended, and I don't think it would make sense to integrate this because the improper integral likely wouldn't converge.

Here's the question:

Evaluate
$$
\iint_R (x^2 - xy + y^2) \, dA
$$
by using the transformation
$$
x = \sqrt{2u} - \sqrt{\frac{2}{3} v} , \quad y = \sqrt{2u} + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3} v}
$$
where (R) is the region bounded by the ellipse (x^2 - xy + y^2 = 2).

$$
\begin{align*}
1. & \ -\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
2. & \ 0 \\
3. & \ 1 \\
4. & \ \frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3} \\
5. & \ \frac{16\sqrt{3}}{9}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The region of integration is *bounded by* the given ellipse, i.e., $R$ is defined as $x^2 - xy + y^2 < 2$.  That will map to a region, not a line, in the $(u,v)$ plane.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks. Now I don't think I can integrate using that region because it's infinite, and the improper integral, integrating u first doesn't converge. The teacher wouldn't have intended the problem to be this way as we haven't covered improper integrals in multi variable calc or infinite regions.

Comment: Ok checking further, a couple of things: (1) the transformation cannot map to the entire region of integration (note for example no values of u and v will produce negative y).  You would have to think of taking a quarter of the ellipse and use some symmetry argument.  Obviously $u$ and $v$ have to be positive.  You will have to think hard about their upper bound.  (2) The correct answer is not in the list unless you have copied something incorrectly - you should expect $\pi$ to appear somewhere.